# EF - pure join table with three or more fields

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, rdbms

at this time i know how to do PJT with two fields for M:N relationships, but i want to know if is possible to do with three or more fields for several M:N relations. I have an example:

Three tables, activities, users, clients. I want to know if is possible, only with navigation properties of the entities do something like: Find activities of one client perfomed by one user:

```
ActivitySet selectedActivities = ClientSet
  .First(c => c.Id == enteredId)
  .Activities.Find(a => a.UserId == enteredUserId);
```

Or any combination possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but you need to go in the opposite direction, from the entity you want, back up.

```
Activities
  .Where(a => a.Client.Id == enteredId)
  .Where(a => a.User.Id == enteredUserId)
```

Comment: But the table structure must be: Activities, clients, users and two more tables: clients_activities and users_activities?

Comment: Not really, your `Activities` table can be a many-to-many table bridging users and clients... You don't even need an `Id` on the Activities, just use `ClientId` and `UserId` as a composite Key.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this?

```
var activities = (from c in ClientSet
                  from a in c.Activities
                  where c.Id = enteredId && a.UserId = enteredUserId);
```